# Can't view postgresql Amazon RDS database tree in SQL client

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, sql-workbench-j

I have created a postgresql DB instance on Amazon RDS, and a database 'rds_test_db'. Then using Workbench/j, I have successfully connected to the test database I have set up. 
But once I connect and go to Database Explorer I only see a top level 'Schemas' with three nested folders: 'public', 'pg_catalog' and 'information_schema'. 
I then successfully ran some create, insert adn select statement to a new dummy table (rds_test_db.public.customers), yet still had no visibility in the database explorer.

Are these some sort of default database folders? Where is my test database 'rds_test_db'?

I can see the 'rds_test_db' listed in datname in pg_catalog.pg_database (along with postgres, template0 and rdsadmin), so it seems like the database I created is there. Perhaps my question should be how do I view a database hierarchy structure in the database explorer?

Comment: Should bè under `public`

Comment: @Banex I don't see the test table which I successfully created in public->table, btw i used create table rds_test_db.public.test (cust_id integer)

Comment: Don't you see your DB under public->rds_test_db?

Comment: I suspect this is a workbench/j issue. Work fine with DataGrip and Toad.